# Calculating Total Line Length of a Network with Shapely: AssertionError

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I would like to calculate the total length of a line network, similar to what is done in [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html) QGIS tutorial.

Here is what I have:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import LineString

length = 0.0
with fiona.open('/Users/felix/data/centerline.shp', 'r') as shp:
    print(shp.crs)
    for rec in shp:
        line = LineString(rec['geometry']['coordinates'])
        length += line.length
```

While this method works fine for some shapefiles, for others it produces this error:

```
{'datum': 'NAD27', 'proj': 'lcc', 'y_0': 0, 'lat_2': 35.46666666666667, 'lat_0': 33.5, 'no_defs': True, 'x_0': 609601.2192024384, 'lon_0': -118, 'lat_1': 34.03333333333333, 'units': 'us-ft'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 200, in geos_linestring_from_py
    array = ob.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felix/Documents/Scripts/python/county_workflow_automation/scratch.py", line 11, in <module>
    line = LineString(rec['geometry']['coordinates'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 94, in _set_coords
    self._geom, self._ndim = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 271, in geos_linestring_from_py
    assert n == 2 or n == 3
AssertionError
```

Can somebody help me interpret this error? Or, if possible, is there a more direct way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I think it is a projection related error..I just tested your code against my data, it worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your version of Shapely ?

Because the error comes from the lines 200-201 of the Shapely file linestring.py

```
    array = ob.__array_interface__
    assert len(array['shape']) == 2
```

With a valid LineString

```
print(ob)
LINESTRING (270818.4477341335 4458997.238866236, 270833.274660459 4458983.162670357, 270830.8347865067 4458975.280000665, 270822.3890689795 4458967.209648361, 270823.3274820381 4458959.702343893, 270822.7644342029 4458958.013200387)
array = ob.__array_interface__
print array
{'version': 3, 'data': <shapely.coords.c_double_Array_12 object at 0x103ba9158>, 'typestr': '<f8', 'shape': (6, 2)}
```

With no error

> array = ob.**array_interface**
>       AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'

You can control if the LineStrings are valids

```
for line in fiona.open('lines_feet.shp'):
    if LineString(line['geometry']['coordinates']).__array_interface__:
        print("ok")
    ok
    ok
    ...
```

**But the easiest way is to use the [shape](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#python-geo-interface) function of Shapely**. The resulting unit is feet (`'units': 'us-ft'` in crs)

```
import fiona
length = 0.0
with fiona.open('lines_feet.shp', 'r') as shp:
print(shp.crs)
for line in shp:
   length += shape(line['geometry']).length
print("{:.2f} in {}".format(length,'feets'))
{'datum': 'NAD27', 'proj': 'lcc', 'y_0': 0, 'lat_2': 35.46666666666667, 'lat_0': 33.5, 'no_defs': True, 'x_0': 609601.2192024384, 'lon_0': -118, 'lat_1': 34.03333333333333, 'units': 'us-ft'}
264.14 in feets
```

or in one line

```
length= sum([shape(line['geometry']).length  for  line in fiona.open("lines_feet.shp")])
print("{:.2f} in {}".format(length,'feets'))
264.14 in feets
```

Comment: I am using shapely version 1.5.17. It appears as though I was attempting to pass MultiLineString geometries into the LineString constructor. Not sure how this happened, but your reference to shapely.geometry.shape() fixed my issue.Thank you very much for your response, gene.